# JQuery not returning successfully

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the call to ajax for posting my form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#GetReport").click(function () {               
            var d = {input:$("#frm").serialize()};                
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Questions/Answer',
                data: JSON.stringify(d),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json", 
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

and this is my action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Answer(string input)
{
    return Content("Success");
}
```

When I press the relevant button, the action gets called but when the value returns, I expect an alert to be displayed saying "Success" but I get nothing despite my action getting called.

Comment: How would that change the output? My action is getting hit and I am able to get the form data. It is only the return statement that I am confused about.

Comment: Have you tried this from your `.asmx`.  It will be easy to find the mistake, if it works from .asmx file then check console for error.

Comment: Remove `dataType: "json",`

Comment: Try `dataType: "text"`, since you seem to be returning a plain string (that is not in JSON format), and `dataType` specifies the expected _response_ format, not the request format.

Comment: Great! removing the datatype did it for me !

Comment: quick, race to make that an answer for those sweet nerd-points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `dataType: "text"`, since you seem to be returning a plain string (that is not in JSON format), and `dataType` specifies the expected *response* format, not the request format. (Or just remove the `dataType` option, in which case jQuery will make its own best guess at the what the response format is once it sees it.)

Comment: But what I dont get is why would having the return type as JSON, redirect me to somewhere else instead of displaying something in the alert right on the same view?

Comment: Because `dataType:"json"` tells jQuery that you're expecting the response to be JSON, so then when your response is _not_ JSON the request has, by definition, failed so your `success` handler is not called. If you add an error handler it should be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Answer(string input)
    {
        return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```